# Yii not resetting primary key counter in fixture tables

Tags: mysql, yii, fixtures

Yii is not resetting the counter for the fixtures on the database. This works on my development server, but on production it does not reset them.

Any ideas why?

Development server

- Mysql 5.6.17
- PHP 5.4.28 (cli)
- Yii 1.1.13

Production Server
*emphasized text*
 - Mysql 5.6.12
 - PHP 5.4.19 (cli)
 - Yii 1.1.13

Comment: try to run this on the database table: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Answer (score 1):

Fixtures are not reset auto increment key. You should specify them explicitly:

```
return array(
    'firstRecord'=>array(
        'id'=>'1',
        'content'=>'First record content',
    ),
    'secondRecord'=>array(
        'id'=>'2',
        'content'=>'Second record content',
    ),
);
```

Or (as say @TotPeRo in comment) you can reset auto increment in `setUpBeforeClass()` method which will be called before the first test of this test class is run.

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
    Yii::app()->db->createCommand('ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')->execute()
}
```

Comment: Oledje, thank you for your time. In fact the fixtures do reset the auto increment key. However, this is only happening on one server but not on the other one. 

On the second option, it does not really help me much because I want a predictable behavior on fixtures. Either they reset or not. 

Right now I solved my problem by querying the models and getting their current primary key.